# change wp user status from wp_users table

Tags: database, user-roles

The `wp_users` table doesn't seem to change when I change a user role from editor to administrator via phpmyadmin when I edit it.

Where is the user's role stored in the WP database? Any clues?

Comment: There are easier ways to change a role of a user from outside of WP, try WP CLI. Of note, roles can be changed by an admin on the users screen

Answer (score 1):

User roles are not stored in `wp_user` table. They are stored as User Metadata.

In `wp_usermeta` you can find two rows for every user:

- `<prefix>capabilities` (for example wp_capabilities) which contains serialized array of [roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles) assigned to that user
- `<prefix>user_level` (for example wp_user_level) which contains [level](https://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels) of given user.

It's important to remember, that keys for these values are prefixed with DB table prefix.